# Difference between std::vector and std::array initializer lists

Tags: c++, arrays, c++11, stdvector, initializer-list

This C++11 code works fine for me:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <array>
using namespace std;

struct str {
    int first, last;
};


vector<str> fields {
    {1,2}, {3,4}, {5,6}
};

int main()
{
    for (str s : fields)
        cout << s.first << " " << s.last << endl;
}
```

It prints the six expected values.

But if I change `vector<str>` to `array<str,3>`, gcc gives me this error: "too many initializers for ‘std::array’".

If I change the initialization of `fields` thus:

```
array<str,3> fields {
    str{1,2}, str{3,4}, str{5,6}
};
```

Things work nicely.

So why do I need `str{1,2}` when using `std::array`, but only `{1,2}` when using `std::vector`?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

See cppreference's section on [aggregate initialization](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/aggregate_initialization).

> The effects of aggregate initialization are:
>
> - Each array element or non-static class member, in order of array subscript/appearance in the class definition, is copy-initialized from
>     the corresponding clause of the initializer list.
> - If the initializer clause is a nested braced-init-list, the corresponding class member is itself an aggregate: aggregate
>     initialization is recursive.

This means that if you had an aggregate inside your struct, such as:

```
struct str {
    struct asdf
    {
        int first, last;
    } asdf; 
};
```

`asdf` would be initialized by the first nested brace-init-list, i.e. `{ { 1, 2 } }`. The reason why you generally need two pairs of braces is because the nested brace-init-list initializes the underlying aggregate in `std::array` (for example, `T a[N]`).

However, you can still initialize your array like this:

```
array<str,3> fields {
    1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6
};
```

or:

```
array<str,3> fields { {
    1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6
} };
```

instead.

On the other hand, how you initialize your vector is covered by [list initialization](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/list_initialization). [`std::vector`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector/vector) has a constructor that accepts an [`std::initializer_list`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/initializer_list).

> The effects of list initialization of an object of type T are:
>
> - Otherwise, the constructors of T are considered, in two phases:
>
>   - All constructors that take `std::initializer_list` as the only argument, or as the first argument if the remaining arguments have
>       default values, are examined, and matched by overload resolution
>       against a single argument of type `std::initializer_list`

Note that you wouldn't be able to initialize your vector ( like this:

```
vector<str> fields {
    1,2, 3,4, 5,6
};
```

but:

```
vector<int> fields {
    1,2, 3,4, 5,6
};
```

is perfectly fine.

Answer (score 4):

It's because array initialization is built a bit different from vector.
To initialize an array you need to use two braces.
Because of a syntax feature you can skip it if you initialize just one object.
So the following is ok:

```
array{1,2,3} -> array{{1,2,3}}
```

But in your example you initialize multiple objects so the compiler doesn't add additional braces. Using two braces fixes that.

```
array<str,3> fields {{
    {1,2}, {3,4}, {5,6}
}};
```