# Which c++ container can contain C int multidimensional arrays (C++03/MSVC11)?

Tags: c++, multidimensional-array, containers, c++03, visual-studio-2012

I have this multidimensional  2 arrays

```
int anArray1[MAX_ROW][MAX_CELL] =
{
    { 0, 1, 1, 0, 1, 1, 1, 0},
    { 0, 1, 1, 0, 1, 1, 1, 0},
    { 0, 1, 1, 0, 1, 1, 1, 0},
    { 0, 1, 1, 0, 1, 1, 1, 0},
    { 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0}
}


int anArray2[MAX_ROW][MAX_CELL] =
{
    { 0, 1, 1, 0, 1, 1, 1, 0},
    { 0, 1, 1, 0, 1, 1, 1, 0},
    { 0, 1, 1, 0, 1, 1, 1, 0},
    { 0, 1, 1, 0, 1, 1, 1, 0},
    { 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0}
}
```

and i want to store them in index based container , i tryed to make another int array that supposed to hold them like this:

```
int LevelsArray[LEVELS_COUNT] = { anArray1, anArray2};
```

im getting this error:

```
error C2440: 'initializing' : cannot convert from 'int [68][8]' to 'int'
```

i guess this is not the correct way .. 
what is the recommended way ?

Comment: They aren't ints. Try making a typedef of the array and an array of that.

Comment: Shouldn't the type of `LevelsArray` be `int[][][]`?

Comment: Short answer: none. Longer answer: it may be possible to instantiate a container of arrays, but you won't be able to do anything useful with it.

Answer (score 5):

I wouldn't consider a plain old array a C++ container. I would rather use a combination of `std::vector` (or `std::array`), because of [*reasons*](http://www.parashift.com/c++-faq/arrays-are-evil.html).

Here's an example:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>

typedef int cell;
typedef std::vector<cell> row;
typedef std::vector<row> level;
typedef std::vector<level> levels;

int main() {
    levels l = 
    {
        {
            { 0, 1, 1, 0, 1, 1, 1, 0},
            { 0, 1, 1, 0, 1, 1, 1, 0},
            { 0, 1, 1, 0, 1, 1, 1, 0},
            { 0, 1, 1, 0, 1, 1, 1, 0},
            { 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0}
        },
        {
            { 0, 1, 1, 0, 1, 1, 1, 0},
            { 0, 1, 1, 0, 1, 1, 1, 0},
            { 0, 1, 1, 0, 1, 1, 1, 0},
            { 0, 1, 1, 0, 1, 1, 1, 0},
            { 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0}
        },
    };
    for (int i = 0; i < l.size(); i++) {
        std::cout << "level " << i << ":\n" ;
        for (row & r : l[i]) {
            for (cell & c : r)
                std::cout << c << " ";
            std::cout << "\n";
        }
        std::cout << "\n";
    }
}
```

The output is:

```
$ g++ test.cc -std=c++11 && ./a.out
level 0:
0 1 1 0 1 1 1 0 
0 1 1 0 1 1 1 0 
0 1 1 0 1 1 1 0 
0 1 1 0 1 1 1 0 
0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 

level 1:
0 1 1 0 1 1 1 0 
0 1 1 0 1 1 1 0 
0 1 1 0 1 1 1 0 
0 1 1 0 1 1 1 0 
0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0
```

Using `std::array` instead could look something like this:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <array>

const int cells_per_row = 8;
const int rows_per_level = 5;
const int nlevels = 2;
typedef int cell;
typedef std::array<cell, cells_per_row> row;
typedef std::array<row, rows_per_level> level;
typedef std::array<level, nlevels> levels;

int main() {
    levels l = 
    {
        level{
            row{ 0, 1, 1, 0, 1, 1, 1, 0},
            row{ 0, 1, 1, 0, 1, 1, 1, 0},
            row{ 0, 1, 1, 0, 1, 1, 1, 0},
            row{ 0, 1, 1, 0, 1, 1, 1, 0},
            row{ 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0}
        },
        level{
            row{ 0, 1, 1, 0, 1, 1, 1, 0},
            row{ 0, 1, 1, 0, 1, 1, 1, 0},
            row{ 0, 1, 1, 0, 1, 1, 1, 0},
            row{ 0, 1, 1, 0, 1, 1, 1, 0},
            row{ 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0}
        },
    };
    for (int i = 0; i < l.size(); i++) {
        std::cout << "level " << i << ":\n" ;
        for (row & r : l[i]) {
            for (cell & c : r)
                std::cout << c << " ";
            std::cout << "\n";
        }
        std::cout << "\n";
    }
}
```

Note that the examples make some use of C++11 features (*initializer lists, range-based for, std::array*) that may not be supported by every compiler. While you can work around the initializer lists to initialize the containers and the range-based for loop for printing, there's no std::array prior to C++11.

For reference:

- http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector
- http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/array
- [Difference between std::vector and std::array initializer lists](https://stackoverflow.com/q/26179353/1025391)
- [What is the easiest way to initialize a std::vector with hardcoded elements?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/2236197/1025391)
- http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/range-for

Comment: im getting initialization with '{...}' is not allowed for object of type "levels"
on the vector example using visual studio 2012

Comment: also give me banch of error with the std::array example like:
'level' : illegal use of this type as an expression

Comment: @user63898 `std::array` became part of C++ with the C++11 standard. You might need to check whether your compiler supports that feature or how you can enable it. (Same goes for the range-based-for loop I've used in the example.) I tested both examples with g++ 4.8.3.

Comment: oo . so its not good i need something that support old compilers ( 2008 ) 
also

Comment: so i guess if  i want pure c++ i stack with the c 3d array

Comment: see below comment the std vector makes me problem also when i try to initialize it

Comment: @user63898 You need to learn about the options you have to initialize a `std::vector` without using initializer lists: http://stackoverflow.com/q/2236197/1025391

Comment: i know this answer thanks for remind me , so its basically dead end for simple solution 
i will go with simple 3d c int array

Answer (score 1):

You can use more explicit declaration of the LevelsArray type

```
int LevelsArray[LEVELS_COUNT][MAX_ROW][MAX_CELL] = { {...}, {...} };
```

However the C++ way would be to use [`std::vector`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector) or [`std::array`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/array) (requires C++11):

```
std::vector<std::vector<std::vector<int>>> LevelsArray =
{
    {
        { 0, 1, 1, 0, 1, 1, 1, 0},
        { 0, 1, 1, 0, 1, 1, 1, 0},
        { 0, 1, 1, 0, 1, 1, 1, 0},
        { 0, 1, 1, 0, 1, 1, 1, 0},
        { 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0}
    },
    {
        { 0, 1, 1, 0, 1, 1, 1, 0},
        { 0, 1, 1, 0, 1, 1, 1, 0},
        { 0, 1, 1, 0, 1, 1, 1, 0},
        { 0, 1, 1, 0, 1, 1, 1, 0},
        { 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0}
    }
};
```

or

```
std::array<std::array<std::array<int, MAX_CELL>, MAX_ROW>, LEVELS_COUNT> LevelsArray =
{
    {
        { 0, 1, 1, 0, 1, 1, 1, 0},
        { 0, 1, 1, 0, 1, 1, 1, 0},
        { 0, 1, 1, 0, 1, 1, 1, 0},
        { 0, 1, 1, 0, 1, 1, 1, 0},
        { 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0}
    },
    {
        { 0, 1, 1, 0, 1, 1, 1, 0},
        { 0, 1, 1, 0, 1, 1, 1, 0},
        { 0, 1, 1, 0, 1, 1, 1, 0},
        { 0, 1, 1, 0, 1, 1, 1, 0},
        { 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0}
    }
};
```

Comment: `int LevelsArray[LEVELS_COUNT][MAX_ROW][MAX_CELL] = { anArray1, anArray2};` wouldn't work, you've to give the array elements inside this array.

Comment: the std::array example gives me :error C2078: too many initializers error

Comment: vector example gives error:
error C2552: 'LevelsArray' : non-aggregates cannot be initialized with initializer list

in visual studio 2012

Comment: @user63898 You need proper C++11 support for initializer list and std:array, using C++03 would be more complicated.

Answer (score 0):

You're missing specifying the other dimensions of the container which depends on the element contained. Try this

```
int LevelsArray[][MAX_ROW][MAX_CELL] =
{
    {
        { 0, 1, 1, 0, 1, 1, 1, 0},
        { 0, 1, 1, 0, 1, 1, 1, 0},
        { 0, 1, 1, 0, 1, 1, 1, 0},
        { 0, 1, 1, 0, 1, 1, 1, 0},
        { 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0}
    },
    {
        { 0, 1, 1, 0, 1, 1, 1, 0},
        { 0, 1, 1, 0, 1, 1, 1, 0},
        { 0, 1, 1, 0, 1, 1, 1, 0},
        { 0, 1, 1, 0, 1, 1, 1, 0},
        { 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0}
    }
};
```

Having the elements (2D arrays) as separate arrays would mean that you cannot store those arrays inside another array; you may only store pointers to them. With this approach, you can refer the inner elements too convienetly with a reference like this

```
auto const &anArray1 = LevelsArray[0];
```

and use it elsewhere.

Comment: is there any way to copy the array to int array not using c++11 and not 
looping all the Level array ?

Comment: C++ as a language doesn't support initializing arrays with arrays. You've to copy them manually or use `std::copy` which too would do the same behind the scenes. If you really want flexible container like you ask, perhaps try `std::vector`.

Comment: the vector make me problems also , see above commnets

Comment: For that you need C++11 where `vector` gets a `std::initializer_list` taking constructor. I don't think VS 2012 has it.